# OpenPyXL how to test if the background of two cells are identical?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a simple problem, all that I would like to do is compare the background colour between two cells to see if the background colours are identical or not.
I have setup a quick test program with a sample spreadsheet where cells A1 and A2 have an identical background. I initially unsuccessfully attempted to use:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color

excel_file = 'sample_color.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
sh = wb['Sheet1']

if sh['A1'].fill.bgColor.rgb == sh['A2'].fill.bgColor.rgb:
    print("Background is identical!")
```

From this code I get no error but it does not successfully identify if the background of two cells are equal. When I print

```
sh['A1'].fill.bgColor.rgb
```

I end up with the following output:

```
Values must be of type <class 'str'>
```

So I have a feeling I am not comparing the right thing

I also tried to get the colour and compare that directly through the folloiwng line of code:

```
color_in_hex = sh['A1'].fill.start_color.index
```

However this code only returned the hexadecimal colour code for certain colours not all the colours that I need so it's not ideal.

The reason I am trying to do this is I am currently trying to automate the migration of an old spreadsheet system to a new format and rows with certain background colours do not need to be migrated. I was planning on having a spreadsheet of 'blacklisted' colours and compare the current rows background against all the currently selected row to decide if it should be added or not.

Comment: Colours can be index, RGB or tints so your code will need to cover different eventualities. It looks like you have indexed colours so you should be comparing these.

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, when I try to compare the index of the two colours (by changing .rgb to .index in the code above) it is saying that the colours that I am trying to compare are equal when they are not. Looking into this further it seems that when attempting to check if two cells with differing background colours they are both returning the value 64 which is incorrectly showing as equal. Reading the following documentation is it possible that they are returning as system colours?https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html

Comment: Indexed colours are always a matter of interpretation but if the index is the same then the colours are the same. It can be helpful if you print the details of the colour objects for relevant cells.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having issues with OpenPyXL getting all the colours correctly .index seems to be legacy and for some formats / colours I am getting a result and others I am getting "must be of type <class 'str'>"

Blank above
Background color index of cell ( 5 1 ) is 00000000
Foreground color index of cell ( 5 1 ) is 00000000
Fomatted from other
Background color index of cell ( 6 1 ) is 00000000
Foreground color index of cell ( 6 1 ) is FF9305FF
Black on white - fill
Background color index of cell ( 7 1 ) is Values must be of type <class 'str'>
Foreground color index of cell ( 7 1 ) is Values must be of type <class 'str'>

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(FileInput,data_only=True)
fs = wb.active
fs_count_row = fs.max_row
# print(fs_count_row)
fs_count_col = fs.max_column
# print(fs_count_col)
# for column in range(1, fs_count_col + 1):
column = 1
for row in range(1,fs_count_row+1):
    cell_obj = fs.cell(column=column, row=row)
    # print(cell_obj.value)
    # print(cell_obj.value, cell_obj.font, cell_obj.fill)
    print(cell_obj.value)
    bgColor = cell_obj.fill.bgColor.rgb
    fgColor = cell_obj.fill.fgColor.rgb
    # if (bgColor=='00000000') or (fgColor=='00000000'):
    #     continue
    # else:
    print("\tBackground color index of cell (",row,column, ") is", bgColor)
    print("\tForeground color index of cell (",row,column, ") is", fgColor)
```

Is there an easy way to dump all formatting?